# getting exception with SQLKorma for syntax: Failure to execute query with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, clojure, sqlkorma

Any idea what is this exception trying to convey ?
I am using sqlKorma with Postgres 9.3.
I am trying to insert multiple rows at once in a table and I am getting a syntax error.

Now neither do I have a "0" anywhere in my query nor am I writing raw SQL to be messing up the syntax.

the korma docs are also not very clear.

```
Failure to execute query with SQL:
DO 0  ::  []
PSQLException:
 Message: ERROR: syntax error at or near "0"
  Position: 4
 SQLState: 42601
 Error Code: 0
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "0"
  Position: 4
```

Thats my code

```
(insert vendor-subsidiary-allowance                                                                                                       
          (values (vec (for [p (seq percentages)]                                                                                           
                         {:id (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)                                                                                   
                          :type "%"                                                                                                         
                          :id_allowance_category (utils.uuid/from-str (p 0))                                                                
                          :id_vendor_subsidiary (allowance-form "vendor_sub_id")                                                            
                          :value  (parse-number (p 1))}))))
```

**NOTE: percentages is a dictionary with uuid strings as keys and value as some numeric string**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want to read [this](http://sqlkorma.com/docs#misc) to find the way to print the generated SQL to console.
You can use `sql-only` or `dry-run` macro to do this.

Print the generated SQL with `sql-only` or `dry-run` and check that the SQL is okay.

Comment: Oh... that is nice! but sql-only is showing placeholders as it is without the values that are going.

Comment: You can also get the SQL text by setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` then getting it from PostgreSQL's logs.